# Fatal Exception Error: main

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

when I try to run a program from a tutorial I recently found for a music player on the android studios emulator,nexus 5 api23, I get an error.
The error is:

```
05-28 21:01:23.267 2937-2937/com.tunein.bryantyoung.tunein E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tunein.bryantyoung.tunein, PID: 2937
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tunein.bryantyoung.tunein/com.tunein.bryantyoung.tunein.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=2937, uid=10066 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2622)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2683)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6066)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:770)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:660)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=2937, uid=10066 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1666)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:502)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:444)
at com.tunein.bryantyoung.tunein.MainActivity.getSongList(MainActivity.java:197)
at com.tunein.bryantyoung.tunein.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:104)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6584)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2683) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6066) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:770) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:660)
```

Not sure what exactly is happening when I run the program that is causing the exception. The main.xml file is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_shuffle"
        android:icon="@drawable/rand"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Shuffle"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_end"
        android:icon="@drawable/end"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="End"/>
</menu>
```

I think the problem is with the lines `android:showAsAction="always"` but when I try to change `android`to `app` and add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">` I still have the same problem with main

the tutorial is [Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764)
thank you

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is  here:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=2937, uid=10066 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

Your app must request permission to access files, try adding this to your app manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

more info: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html

Comment: I agree with goatcheeze this line MainActivity.java:197 is reading a protected external storage so follow his advise.

Comment: after adding the line of code the problem persisted could it be the emulator?